# Equation of continuity seemingly violated

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

Flow rate is volume of liquid flown per unit time. Suppose I make the time interval so small that it nearly becomes a time instant. When observed at that time instant the volume flown through larger area must be higher than the volume through lower area.

[image]

Shouldn't that be against the *equation of continuity* which says that the flow rate must be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the volume only in time, but you are forgetting how volume is calculated in the first place:

$$dV = A \cdot ds$$

where $A$ is the cross-section area and $ds$ is the *infinitesimally small tube length* for which you are calculating the *infinitesimally small volume*:

$$ds = v \cdot dt \tag 1$$

where $v$ is the fluid velocity and $dt$ is the *infinitesimally small time*. The Eq. (1) is key to understanding where your reasoning is wrong - for the same time $dt$ the fluid *covers longer distance through smaller cross-section area*, which we prove via mass flow.

The *infinitesimally small mass* flowing into the tube across $A$ in time $dt$ is:

$$dm = \rho \cdot dV = \rho \cdot A \cdot v \cdot dt$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid density which is constant for incompressible fluids.

Since the mass is not stored in the system, for any two points in the tube we have

$$dm_1 = dm_2 \quad \text{or} \quad A_1 v_1 = A_2 v_2$$

Continuity is not violated since water speed at the two points is different. In other words, for infinitesimal small time $dt$ the fluid covers greater distance $ds$ for smaller cross-section area $A$. You have simply neglected the effect $dt$ has on $ds$ and assumed that $ds$ is constant.